# Create subdomain out of sight the wp multisite

Tags: multisite, subdomains

Because of some reasons I had installed a WordPress in multisite mode.

Due to apache mod_rewrite and wild card activation on the server, the control of all subdomains goes under WordPress control!

I use direct admin. So now I have no FTP access! what can I do for this?

I also want to create some subdomains, that is not under WordPress control!.

how can I do this?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: Hy Matthew, thanks. but do you have any answer to my question?

Comment: If I was to guess, I would say that you've got the wild card in your DNS config before your FTP etc.. move the specialist subs before the wildcard entry. If you need help with server config, there are specialist SE server management sites for that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely investigate this case